# Can nitroglycerin medication cause problems when going through airport security?

Tags: health, airport-security

It's well documented that bottles of sublingual nitroglycerin spray *are* allowed in carry-on and checked baggage, as an essential personal medication:

> #### Nitroglycerin medication
>
> - Carry on baggage: Yes
> - Checked baggage: Yes
>
> Nitroglycerin medication: Liquid prescription medications are exempted
> from the liquid restrictions and can be carried in carry-on baggage in
> volumes larger than 100 ml (3.4 oz.). These liquids must be declared
> to the Screening Officer separately. To facilitate screening, CATSA
> recommends that the medication be properly labelled (professionally
> printed label identifying the medication or a manufacturer’s name or
> pharmaceutical label).
> — [Nitroglycerin medication - CATSA](https://www.catsa-acsta.gc.ca/en/what-can-bring/item/nitroglycerin-medication)

But, do problems occur when going through airport security if some of the medication has accidentally (or perhaps intentionally as a "joke") contaminated one's luggage or clothing?

Comment: Related : [Taking wet things through airport security](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50175/118049)

Comment: You might get swabbed and they might detect it; I'm not sure how likely but e.g. a paramedic or pharmacist might test positive. The first result of a positive test would be getting asked some questions, and you would be able to make your case. But you might get searched or be temporarily detained. I'd be sure to allow plenty of time to clear security. I'm not sure how somebody would play a joke on you but that's between you and your travelling companions.

Comment: @StuartF, I put "joke" in quotation marks. Suppose I'm at the airport and some stranger there cuts in line in front of me. I then decide to be an idiot and use my spray on their luggage when they aren't looking. They aren't going to be able to "make their case" when they are pulled out of line for trying to smuggle explosives onto the plane. I'm just wondering whether this kind of thing ever happens and how it is handled.

Comment: @RayButterworth: It sounds like such an unusual circumstance would be similar to [Airport security: what if I carry an item with traces of explosive?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/airport-security-what-if-i-carry-an-item-with-traces-of-explosive).

Comment: @GregHewgill, yes, and the answer is basically that false positives aren't uncommon, so it would likely result in the minor inconvenience of a hand check of the luggage contents. ¶ That suggested question didn't turn up in my site search because "nitroglycerin" appears only in its comments, and not in the Question or any of its Answers. ¶ Feel free to vote this question as a duplicate (I just did).